# Local minimum and gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

But the proof here below is specially elegant.

Is there any function $f$ such that $f$ has a local minimum at $x$ but $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$?

Only assumption on $f$ is that it has to be differentiable at $x$ so that I can write $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$  to ask you this question.

Comment: no: differentiable at local minimum implies grad f=0

Comment: ok... and is it possible to prove it?

Comment: apply the definition of differentiability

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392952/proof-of-if-x-0-in-mathbb-rn-is-a-point-of-local-minimum-of-f-then-nab?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f'(0) \neq 0$, then $\lim_{t \to 0} {f(t)-f(0) \over t} = f'(0)$. Suppose $f'(0) >0$, then the limit says that for some $\delta>0$ we have 
${f(t)-f(0) \over t} \ge {1 \over 2} f'(0)$ whenever $|t|<\delta$. In particular, $f(t) \le f(0) + {1 \over 2} t f'(0)$ whenever $t \in (-\delta,0]$. Hence $0$ is not a minimizer. A similar analysis shows the same when $f'(0) < 0$.

Now take a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $\nabla \phi(x) \neq 0$. Let 
$f(t) = \phi(x+t \nabla \phi(x))$. We have
$f'(0) = \|\nabla \phi(x)\|^2>0$, hence $x$ is not a local minimizer for $\phi$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!