# Global Extrema of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact. For simplicity, let's say $E$ is a closed ball. Let $f$ be a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We know that global maximum exists in $E$, and it is either on $\partial E$ or in $E^o$. Then, is the following true?

If global maximum takes place at $p \in E^o$, then $p$ must be a critical point, i.e. $Df(p) = 0$.

I think this is false as I've seen some examples that a function with a unique local extrema (wlog take min) with unique critical point fails to attain global minimum at this point, given that the function is defined in **open set**. ([Unique critical point does not imply global maximum/global minimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121326/unique-critical-point-does-not-imply-global-maximum-global-minimum)) Things get really rough in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I would appreciate if you all can provide some insight!

Comment: The statement is true. By $D$, I assume you mean the gradient.

Comment: @OliverJones Would you mind if you can elaborate your answer, why a global maximum needs to be a local maximum? The idea I have is, can't you do some twisting and bendings on the plane to force the maximum to have non-zero Derivative

Comment: You're not being clear. A global maximum must be a local maximum; just use the definition. You're asking why the gradient is zero at local extrema?

Comment: for some $r>0$, and $\forall x \in B(p,r): f(x) \leq f(p)$

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Here's a proof for the case of local minimums: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/392957/55622

Answer (score 1):

A global maximum is also a local maximum and $Df(p)=0$ is true for any local maximum.